# Xamarin.Forms stepper is showing only minus button on android

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]

This only shows minus option on the stepper. Why the plus option is not visible? The stepper works just fine on iOS.

```
<Entry  Text="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Entry>
 <Stepper Value="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        MinimumWidthRequest="200"></Stepper>
```

Comment: post your used XAML code here

Comment: added the stepper along with related entry for showing values. By the way, MinimumWidthRequest didn't work.

Comment: @ShahzadLatif You should show the full Code of Grid , then we will check where problem is .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried shared code in my Grid , it works .

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="400" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Entry  Text="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"></Entry>
    <Stepper Value="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="0"
             MinimumWidthRequest="200"></Stepper>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="0"
             BackgroundColor="Red" />

    <Button Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</Grid>
```

The effects :

[image]

If you have a doubt about **[MinimumWidthRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.minimumwidthrequest?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.MinimumWidthRequest)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=xamarin-forms#remarks)** , it can be affected by **Layout** . If using it in `StackLayout` , then it will work , however in `Grid` can not .

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Entry  Text="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="123456789" MinimumWidthRequest="5"
                 ></Entry>
        <Stepper Value="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 MinimumWidthRequest="1"></Stepper>
  </StackLayout>
```

The effects :

[image]

**In addition** , from **Remarks** of `MinimumWidthRequest` :

> This causes overflow handling to shrink this element to its minimum width before elements who do not have a minimum size set.

I think it just be used to shrink the element , if the element not be supported the limit size , then it will not work .Here **Stepper** is not recommended for using `MinimumWidthRequest`. If works, it will cause it to appear asymmetric.

Comment: it was due to the space issue. I put it in a bigger column and now it's showing up properly. MinimumWidthRequest was unnecessary.